# Check tag classes with watir?

Tags: css, ruby, class, watir

I have a div that changes based on if the form was submitted correctly or not.
I wanted to know if it's possible to check a specific element for a class or not?

Starting out the element looks like this.

```
<div id="myerrortest" class="input text"></div>
```

If the input isn't correct add the error class.

```
<div id="myerrortest" class="input text error"></div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.div(:id => "myerrortest").class_name
```

More information:

http://watir.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/HTMLElement.html#class_name-instance_method

Another alternative would be to just see if the div with class you expect exists or not

```
browser.div((:id => "myerrortest", :class => 'input text').exists?
```

If using rSpec type matchers it would be

```
browser.div((:id => "myerrortest", :class => 'input text').should exist
```

Comment: You could also look to see if a div with the id and class you expect exists or not, I've taken the liberty of editing Zeljko's answer to include that option as well.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden: if you had created another answer, I would upvote it, but now I get all the upvotes :)

Comment: sometimes it's better to just improve an answer that is already correct and make it better, than have two competing correct answers.  it's not all about who gets the most rep points after all, but helping our users.. (feel free to upvote this comment however :-) )

Comment: Well, both answers would be correct, it is not like they are competing. Upvoted the comment, by the way. :)

Comment: Nice I like both ideas, the ability to get all classes is helpful and the simple does this tag exist works for what I wanted with out having to parse the classes. Thanks Željko and Chuck for both answers and the good comments about how members of this site should think.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with jquery (or not, jquery sintax is only more simple but with getelement you can do anything).

This is an example that add class with a button click:

```
$(".button").click(function(){  
$("#myerrortest").attr("class",$("#myerrortest").attr("class")+" error");
});
```

this work also with $(".classname").
Hope it help